# C++ CIMG suddenly stopped opening display

Tags: c++, x11, cimg

I have now been working on a c++ project for quite some time now. I have been opening the display with the same method every time, passing a set path into a `CImg<unsigned char>` and then passing that object into the `CImgDisplay`, quite standard, and it worked every time. Then, I started passing the path through command-line arguments, which also worked perfectly well. However, once I switched back to hardcoding the path in order to use the debugger in VS Code, the program started spitting out a very descriptive error:

[image: Exception has occurred]

After doing some digging around, I found a bit better of a description of the error:

```cpp
[CImg] *** CImgDisplayException *** [instance(0,0,0,[untitled])] CImgDisplay::assign(): Failed to open X11 display.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cimg_library::CImgDisplayException: [instance(0,0,0,[untitled])] CImgDisplay::assign(): Failed to open X11 display.
```

When running the program from the command-line (compiles perfectly), the error is a `Segmentation fault: 11`.

I tried to look online for the same error, even not related to CIMG as this is an X11-related error, but couldn't find anything. The error persisted when I commented out the whole main function instead of the two image and display declaration lines. The code is like follows:

```cpp
#define cimg_use_png
#include "CImg.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

int main(/*int argc, char *argv[]*/) {
    //CImg<unsigned char> og_pic(argv[1]), first_anim(og_pic.width(),og_pic.height(),1,3,127);
    CImg<unsigned char> og_pic("/Users/glebsvarcer/Desktop/my-stupid-little-programs/maze_solver/test13.png");
    CImgDisplay disp(og_pic, "Test");

    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling with

```
clang++ -g /Users/glebsvarcer/Desktop/my-stupid-little-programs/maze_solver/cleanup_pic.cpp -O2 -lm -pthread -I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -pthread -lX11 -o cleanup -Dcimg_use_png -lpng && rm out.txt ; cleanup >> out.txt
```

What could be causing this? I really can't move on in the project without the debugger, and would be really grateful if anyone has a solution to this.

Comment: Is your `DISPLAY` environment variable set?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Could you please clarify? Still pretty new. I haven't configured it before, as it just, well, worked.

Comment: Before I do that, can you state what your operating system is please? And also whether or not you are using a programming IDE and how exactly you are compiling and running the app? Thanks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I use macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and Visual Studio Code. I compile through a terminal with the command in the post and then just run the executable. If I need the debugger, I compile with breakpoints through VS Code with the same command

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things that seem wrong here.

- Have you installed **XQuartz**?
- Can you run `xterm` and it shows up correctly?
- Have you really got X11 in `/usr/X11R6`? I have never seen that on a Mac. Please try running `ls -lR /usr/X11R6`
- Have you tried specifying an actual C++ standard in your `clang++` command? E.g. `clang++ -std=c++11 ...`
- You should specify `-Dcimg_display` on your `clang++` command if you want to use X11
- You don't need to `#define cimg_use_png` in your source file **AND** in the compilation command-line, just do it in the latter so it is done before any other `#includes` and for every compilation unit
- If you want to use PNG images, you should also link `zlib` in the compilation command. i.e. `-lz`